Threshold seems to break my website, IntersectionObserver not working as intended
Recently I've tried to follow a youtube tutorial on scroll animations using IntersectionObserver, I followed step by step but it seems when min-weight is set to 100vh, 2 sections load in at the same time, not allowing the 2nd one to ever change.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Scroll Tutorial Beyond Fireship</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script defer src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <section class="hidden">
        <h1>Hi Mom!</h1>
        <p>This is my website</p>
    </section>

    <section class="hidden">
        <h2>Buy my products</h2>
        <p>
            The things you own end up owning you.
            It's only after you lose everything that you're free to do anything
        </p>
    </section>

    <section class="hidden">
        <h2>It's really good</h2>
        <div class="logos">
            <div class="logo hidden">
                <img src="Images/icons8-steam-75.png">
            </div>
            <div class="logo hidden">
                <img src="Images/icons8-nintendo-switch-logo-75.png">
            </div>
            <div class="logo hidden">
                <img src="Images/icons8-ps5-75.png">
            </div>
            <div class="logo hidden">
                <img src="Images/icons8-xbox-75.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

</body>
</html>`

`let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
        console.log(entry) //check
        if (entry.isIntersecting){
            entry.target.classList.add('show');
        } else{
            entry.target.classList.remove('show');
        }
    })
});

let hiddenElements = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden');
hiddenElements.forEach((el) => observer.observe(el));`

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;400;700&display=swap');
body{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

section{
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.hidden{
    opacity: 0;
    filter: blur(5px);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: all 1.5s;
}
.show{
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
}
.logos{
    display: flex;
}
.logo{
    margin: 1rem;
}
.logo:nth-child(2){
    transition-delay: 200ms;
}
.logo:nth-child(3){
    transition-delay: 400ms;
}
.logo:nth-child(4){
    transition-delay: 600ms;
}

@media(prefers-reduced-motion){
    .hidden{
        transition: none;
    }
}

I tried setting min-height to 101vh which works, and adding threshold 0.5, which breaks my website.
